# XPages jsonRpcService - Possible to get SMD description remotely?

Tags: jsf, xpages, lotus-domino, json-rpc, smd

I'm using the Domino 8.5.3 Extension Library with the jsonRpcService but I'm not generating the page content from the XPage, just using it as a service provider.

Is there any way to generate the SMD automatically from the XPage content?

I see that it is done by the control when it generates client-side code so I know it must be possible.

How can I get the service descriptor in a way that I can control so that it only returns the SMD, not the whole block of generated Javascript?

Comment: Do you mean get the smd object itself from the jsonRpcService client side object?

Comment: No, I mean get the SMD object from the server side code. I realize that it auto-generates the client side SMD but I'm coding Dojo outside of XPages while still taking advantage of Domino's features like JsonRest and JsonRpc. Dojo can load an SMD via a URL, that's what I'd like to do, if possible.